# html iframe display and control in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

when I have HTML content with text, images and iframes I know I can display the HTML using a flutter_html package or other similar packages, but none of them supporting the iframe until now...I headed to the webview package which displays the whole HTML content but I can not control the size or the direction of the content If the content is on Arabic...any idea about displaying the iframe without using the webview, or using the webview with the option of at least control the HTML content and text direction?
Thanks in advance

[image of the current text direction demonstrating my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53uDN.jpg)

```
"<p>موجز الأخبار ليوم الأربعاء 27-3-2019:</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p><iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/qvW_wqCMkKQ\" width=\"400\" height=\"300\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe></p>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lot of searching I decided to try out changing in the HTML it self..so I added this tag to the existing HTML-note that I added it after searching and I have never dealt with HTML before and Do not know What they call these additions so I named it a tag-

```
"<font size='$textsize'face='Cairo'dir='rtl'><p>موجز الأخبار ليوم الأربعاء 27-3-2019:</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p><iframe          src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/qvW_wqCMkKQ\"   width=\"400\" height=\"300\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe></p></font>"
```

Hope that it will help some one in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking. But what I picked was that you want to be able to control the dimensions of the WebView.

If that is the case you can use the [Container()](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) class. i.e wrap the Webview widget as a child of a container

```
  Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0), //set the margin for the container
    width: 48.0, // width
    height: 48.0, //height
    child: YourWebViewComponent()

  )
```

Let me know if thats what you wanted.

Comment: I want to control the text direction of the Html content inside the web view and change it to be right to left instead of left to right

Comment: I have added a photo to demonstrate the issue